Riemann Sum with Supremum
Suppose we have $f(t, \mathbf{s}): \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{g}$ where
$\mathbf{s} \in [0, 1]^{g}$ with $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \cup \infty$,
$t \in \mathbf{t}$ where $\mathbf{t}$ is a set of tagged points on an arbitrary interval $[a, b]$ with uniform spacing (equal distance to nearby tagged points) and $t_{i}^{(n)}$ represents the element at $i$-th position of the set $\mathbf{t}$ with $\lvert\mathbf{t}\rvert=n$,
and $f$ is a continuous function and differentiable on such interval $[a, b]$ w.r.t. $t$ and $\forall s \in \mathbf{s}$.
Does the following expression hold (by applying the definition of Riemann Integration)?
$$
\begin{align*}
&
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n}
    \sup_{\mathbf{s} \in [0, 1]^{g}} 
        f(t_{i}^{(n)}, \mathbf{s})
        (
            t_{i+1}^{(n)}
            -
            t_{i}^{(n)}
        )
    =
    \int_{b}^{a}
    \sup_{\mathbf{s} \in [0, 1]^{g}} 
        f(t, \mathbf{s})
    d{t}
    \enspace .
\end{align*}
$$
